# Rich Text (YUI) Editor Broken on IE11

Tags: internet-explorer, editor, yui, internet-explorer-11

I'm running Internet Explorer 11 and YUI 2: Rich Text Editor seems not working. Please see attached screen shot for more detail. Any ideas how to fix this under IE11?

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't this be reported to YUI and not here? File a bug. And shouldn't you move to YUI3?

Comment: Hi there, I'm a member of the YUI team. If you have a JSFiddle/Bin of the issue, or any site we can take a look at, we're definitely more than happy to help you out! @epascarello is correct that YUI2 is no longer officially supported, but we can still help you as much as we can.

Comment: @ClarenceLeung, thanks! You could just go to YUI 2 official website using IE 11 to see the result. http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/editor/simple_adv_editor.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For IE changed its User-Agent, YUI(2.9) need a surgery.

1. Modify yahoo-dom-event.js:
   Find this: YAHOO.env.parseUA, then at last add something that tell YAHOO.env.ua now is undering IE 11. like this:

   ```
    if (g.ie == 0 && c.indexOf('Trident') != -1){
        g.ie = 11;
    }
   ```
2. Modify editor.js:
   Find the `_setInitialContent` function, and  after the if-branch that includes "BackCompat",
   add this:

   ```
   this.browser = YAHOO.env.parseUA();
   ```

   then just in the following if-branch (`if (this.browser.ie || this.browser.webkit || this.browser.opera || (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Firefox/1.5') != -1))`):
   add this:

   ```
    if (this.browser.ie == 11) {
        this.browser.ie = 0;
    }
   ```

Hope Works, Good Luck!

Comment: Worked Perfectly! - Nothing like the scramble when the sales manager says: "Uh, we can't add notes to these orders. Can you get it fixed before they all log in this morning?"

Answer (score 2):

kinglomei's solution works, but you might have to modify it slightly to get it to work for you.
In YUI, that parseUA function can be defined in many different places depending on how you set up your website; ours happens to define it in the yahoo.js file, but it is often defined in utilies, yuiloader, yui-dom-event, and yahoo-dom-event, as kinglomei stated.

If you are using the minified code, kinglomei's solution works perfectly, but if you are referencing the debug or just unminified code, your code should look like this instead (the minification renames the variables):

```
 if (o.ie == 0 && ua.indexOf('Trident') != -1){
     o.ie = 11;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I posted this elsewhere but thought it applies here as well:

I'm using 2.7.0b on a legacy site. Just understand that none of these "fixes" will be exact for you unless you are using the exact same version of the library. This is because as each one was "minimized" various characters were used for the sake of minimization. So you may have to do some hunting. ALSO, bear in mind, this may be different for you depending on if you are using yahoo.js by itself, yahoo-dom-event.js or as in my case, utilities.js. So you will need to make adjustments accordingly.

### Step 1:

In utilities/utilities.js & yahoo-dom-event/yahoo-dom-event.js on ln 7 Character 1592 (ln 396 of yahoo.js):
Right after:

```
if(A&&A[1]){C.caja=parseFloat(A[1]);}
```

But before:

```
return C;}();
```

Add this:

```
if (C.ie==0&&B.indexOf('Trident')!=-1){C.ie=11;}
```

### Step 2:

In editor/editor-min.js & editor/simpleeditor-min.js on line 13 Character 2078 (ln 3135 of editor.js & ln 3135 of simpleeditor.js)

Right after:

```
(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox/1.5")!=-1)){
```

But before:

```
try{if(this.browser.air)
```

Add this:

```
if(this.browser.ie==11){this.browser.ie=0;}
```